# How does javascript's 'this' binding work when assigning a "method" to another variable?

Tags: javascript, this

Consider:

```
function Thing() {
    this.prop = null
}

Thing.prototype.whoIsThis = function() {
    console.log(this)
}

a = new Thing()
a.whoIsThis()      // logs '> Thing {...}'

f = a.whoIsThis
f()                // logs '> Window {...}'
```

So `this` is not bound to the `Thing` in the second call. How does `this` work in this situation? Isn't `a.whoIsThis` a "method" of a `Thing` regardless of any variable its assigned to?

Comment: Context is set at the time the function is called. `a.whoIsThis` just returns the function, it doesn't have any context.

Comment: Well, if it's saying window, then it definitely is being weird. This is unusual, as I've always heard that "functions are in the scope of where they are defined"

Comment: @Markasoftware It's not weird. The value of `this` in the global context is `window`. You have to do `a.f()` to call it with a different context.

Comment: so this is the context, not the scope, and those are different things?

Comment: I think `this` is pretty well explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Not to mention the other thousand questions about "this" topic (see right hand column).

Comment: @Markasoftware Simply put, scope defines the visibility of an object and `this` refers to the current object on which the function is invoked.

Comment: You may also want to check out the [MDN docs for call, apply, bind, etc.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `a.whoIsThis`, it will refer the function object only. The function object will have no reference to the object on which it is attached. But when you invoke the function, JavaScript dynamically decides the current object and sets that as `this` inside the function.

This dynamicity allows us to use any object as the current object in the runtime.

But when you simply invoke a function object, without any object reference, by default, JavaScript will set `this` as the global object (`window` object in browser) and in Strict mode, `this` will be set to `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Literally "the context" of the function call determines what `this` will be

Comment: @ChaseMeadors: Yep. The value of `this` is determined by how the function is *called* (unless it is bound to a specific value via `.bind`).

Answer (score 0):

A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. In most cases, the value of **'this' is determined by how a function is called, when 'this' is inside a function.**

1) When a function is ***called as a method of an object***, its this is set to the object the method is called on.

2) When a function is ***called directly***, the value of this is not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value of this must always be an object so it defaults to the global object. In strict mode, the value of this remains at whatever it's set to when entering the execution context, so 'undefined'.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

This binding is decided at run time and not at author time

having `f = a.whoIsThis` is just another reference to the function WhoIsThis

now Imagine If you have the function declared in the global scope..which is really what `f` is now..and when calling `f` JS at run time run the function as if it was declared in the global scope(as I mentioned) so It asks ..what `this` refers to if I'm in the global scope => default binding rule would answer..it's simply the global(window) object